# Easy way to convert int [,] to int [] [] in F#

Tags: f#

We have two arrays

```
let a = [| [|1|] |]
```

and

```
let a' = Array2D.init 1 1 (fun x y -> 1)
```

the first returns int [][] and the second int [,]

Is there an easy way to convert int[,] to int [][] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no built-in functions to do this. I would use list comprehension syntax, that would seem straightforward:

```
let a =
   [| for i in 0..(Array2D.length1 a' - 1) ->
         [| for j in 0..(Array2D.length2 a' - 1) -> a'.[i,j] |] |]
```

One thing to look out for is the base index. In your example the array is zero-based, so I used zeroes just to make the code shorter. But if you need to support the case of non-zero-based arrays, you have to do `a'.[ i + Array2D.base1 a',  j + Array2D.base2 a' ]` instead. Not quite as elegant, but watchagonnado.

Comment: Its almost the correct answer, add a couple of -1 to the Array2D.length s and you are correct. As it is I get IndexOutOfRangeException. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Good catch. Sorry, I was writing from my phone, couldn't verify the code.

Answer (score 1):

If it's the building of the array you're interested in, you can build the `[][]` (aka jagged array) form by using two `Array.init`

e.g.

`Array.init 10 (fun r -> Array.init 20 (fun c -> (c+r)))`

`[|[|0; 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10; 11; 12; 13; 14; 15; 16; 17; 18; 19|];
    [|1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10; 11; 12; 13; 14; 15; 16; 17; 18; 19; 20|];
    [|2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10; 11; 12; 13; 14; 15; 16; 17; 18; 19; 20; 21|];`...